# Evaluate: $ \sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{[\ln(2019)]^i}{i!}$

Tags: limits

> Evaluate: $$ \sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{[\ln(2019)]^i}{i!}$$

---

First of all, we know the sum converges as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{[\ln(2019)]^n}{n!} =0$$ as we have an exponential on numerator and factorial on denominator. Now, I'm stuck on evaluating the limit, I thought of using riemnan sums, but I wasn't able to do so. Please help

Comment: $$\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{4!} + \ldots$$

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia oh right, Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{x}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!}$$
put $x:=\ln(2019)$
$$e^{\ln(2019)}=\sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{[\ln(2019)]^i}{i!}
=2019$$